# iPhone like Spinner for Android

Tags: android, custom-controls, android-spinner

I Need a custom behavior for android as it is in `iPhone`.

[image]

Currently I need an arrangement for selecting the numbers as given in the above picture.
I tried http://code.google.com/p/customspinner/  , but there is no API to set the current value, we can get only the current value set. I should be able to keep set the current value to lets say 70 and this should work for different resolution android devices.